# UIPicker interaction between them

Tags: ios, uipicker

I have 2 pickerviews on screen. Both populate rotate and taps return
correct and expected results. They are distinguished by the TAG
property using the "if/switch" statement in the necessary delegate
methods.

What I'd like is forpicker1 to change the selected row in picker2
dynamically during runtime as the user interacts.
E.g.
  picker1 has values 1 to 10
  Picker2 has values red, blue, green, purple etc

User taps row with value 2 in picker1 and automatically picker2
rotates/animates to predetermined row say purple in this case, user then taps picker1 again row 5 and again picker2 is animated/rotated to another predetermined row, and so on

What works:

The two pickers are created in viewDidLoad and
        [picker2 selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:NO];
works with no issues, but only first time round at initial view load.
Its does not change the selected row if called from

What does NOT work is calls to:
       [picker2 selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:NO]; from other (delegate) methods, even if I call:
       [self.thePicker reloadAllComponents];

Does this work at all, or is it not supposed to do this? I'm new to this forum, so apologies in advance if I'm being thick! I have trolled look for the answer though
Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't have to reloadAllComponents, selectRow:inComponent:animated: should work. If you log picker2 does it give you what you expect? You should post the code where you're calling the selectRow:inComponent:animated method.